# An identity for an integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

This problem is from H. Lamb's infinitesimal calculus.

> If $f(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ be finite and continuous, and if $\phi(x)$ retain the same sign, throughout the interval from $x = a$ to $x = b$, then
>   \begin{align}
> \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx = f[a + \theta (b-a)] \, \int_{a}^{b} \phi(x) \, dx,
> \end{align}
>   where $0 < \theta < 1$.

The questions here are:

1. What are some ways to prove this integral identity ?
2. What are some applications of this identity in terms of commonly seen integrals ?

Answer (score 2):

Assume WLOG that $\phi$ is non-negative.

Put $\alpha = \displaystyle \min_{x \in [a,b]}f(x)$ and $\beta = \displaystyle \max_{x \in [a,b]}f(x)$, then:

$$\alpha\int_a^b\phi(x) \ dx≤\int_a^bf(x)\phi(x) \ dx≤\beta\int_a^b\phi(x) \ dx$$

Divide by $\int_a^b \phi (x) \ dx$ and apply the intermediate value theorem to $f$. In case $\int_a^b \phi(x) \ dx$ is $0$, by continuity $\phi \equiv 0$ and the conclusion is trivial.

Regarding applications, I'm not really sure, I've used occasionally to obtain bounds for improper integrals which may otherwise be cumbersome to calculate.